# Property of Absolutely continuous measures.

Tags: measure-theory

On the Royden's book there is written:

"If $\nu << \mu$ and a property holds a.e.[$\mu$], then it holds a.e.[$\nu$]."
Chap.11.6

but wait: absolute continuity of $\nu$ respect to $\mu$, ($\nu << \mu$), means that if $\mu(A)=0$ for some A in the sigma-algebra of the measurable space, then $\nu(A)=0$.

But there can exist sets B, such that $\nu(B)=0$ and $\mu(B) \neq 0$.
Does the assertion in the Royden's book forgets this possibility?

Answer (score 4):

No, the book does not. But there is no problem: Suppose $P(x)$ holds for $\mu$-a. e. $x \in \Omega$, then there is an $A$ with $\mu(A) = 0$ and $P(x)$ for every $x \in A^c$. As $\nu \ll \mu$, $\nu(A) = 0$, that is $P(x)$ holds for $\nu$-a. e. $x \in \Omega$, namely for all $x \in A^c$ and $\nu(A) = 0$.

Comment: thank you for the quick elucidation :-)